# Add a user to a group Unattend.xml

Tags: unattended-processing, unattend-file

I created the following Unattend.xml file. The only problem is it won't add the Users to the Users group.

I'm searching on google on what I'm doing wrong but I just can't seem to find out what the issue is. It should work according to the documentation that I found. I used the Windows System Image Manager to create this file.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend" >
    < settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name = "Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State">
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                    <InstallFrom>
                        <Path>.\Operating Systems\os\os.wim</Path>
                        <MetaData>
                            <Key>/IMAGE/INDEX</Key>
                            <Value>1</Value>
                        </MetaData>
                    </InstallFrom>
                    <InstallToAvailablePartition>true</InstallToAvailablePartition>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <ComplianceCheck>
                <DisplayReport>OnError</DisplayReport>
            </ComplianceCheck>
            <UserData>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
                <ProductKey>
                    <Key>WindowsSerialKey</Key>
                    <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
                </ProductKey>
                <Organization>Stuiter</Organization>
            </UserData>
            <EnableFirewall>true</EnableFirewall>
            <EnableNetwork>true</EnableNetwork>
            <Restart>Restart</Restart>
        </component>
        <component name = "Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass = "generalize" >
        < component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DoNotCleanTaskBar>true</DoNotCleanTaskBar>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass = "oobeSystem" >
        < component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State">
            <UserAccounts>
                <AdministratorPassword>
                    <Value>hashed password</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </AdministratorPassword>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action= "add" >
                        < Password >
                            < Value > hashed password</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Group>Users</Group>
                        <Description>User</Description>
                        <DisplayName>User account</DisplayName>
                        <Name>User</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action= "add" >
                        < Password >
                            < Value > hashed password</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Description>Admin user</Description>
                        <DisplayName>Admin user account</DisplayName>
                        <Name>AdminUser</Name>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                    </LocalAccount>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action= "add" >
                        < Password >
                    < Value > hashed password</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Description>User for Support</Description>
                        <DisplayName>Support user account</DisplayName>
                        <Group>Users</Group>
                        <Name>Support</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <AutoLogon>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <Username>Rimote</Username>
                <Domain>.</Domain>
                <Password>
                    <Value>hashed password</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <LogonCount>2147483647</LogonCount>
            </AutoLogon>
            <Display>
                <ColorDepth>32</ColorDepth>
                <HorizontalResolution>1</HorizontalResolution>
                <RefreshRate>60</RefreshRate>
                <VerticalResolution>1</VerticalResolution>
                <DPI>120</DPI>
            </Display>
            <FirstLogonCommands>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action= "add" >
                    < CommandLine > wscript.exe % SystemDrive %\LTIBootstrap.vbs</CommandLine>
                    <Description>Lite Touch new OS</Description>
                    <Order>1</Order>
                </SynchronousCommand>
            </FirstLogonCommands>
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>false</HideEULAPage>
                <ProtectYourPC>2</ProtectYourPC>
                <HideLocalAccountScreen>false</HideLocalAccountScreen>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>false</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>false</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>false</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
                <UnattendEnableRetailDemo>false</UnattendEnableRetailDemo>
            </OOBE>
            <RegisteredOrganization>Stuiter</RegisteredOrganization>
            <RegisteredOwner>Stuiter</RegisteredOwner>
            <TimeZone>W.Europe Standard Time</TimeZone>
            <BluetoothTaskbarIconEnabled>false</BluetoothTaskbarIconEnabled>
            <ConvertibleSlateModePromptPreference>1</ConvertibleSlateModePromptPreference>
            <DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>false</DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>
            <DoNotCleanTaskBar>false</DoNotCleanTaskBar>
            <EnableStartMenu>false</EnableStartMenu>
            <ShowPowerButtonOnStartScreen>false</ShowPowerButtonOnStartScreen>
            <SignInMode>1</SignInMode>
            <WindowsFeatures>
                <ShowInternetExplorer>false</ShowInternetExplorer>
                <ShowMediaCenter>false</ShowMediaCenter>
                <ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>false</ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>
            </WindowsFeatures>
        </component>
        <component name = "Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass = "offlineServicing" >
        < component name="Microsoft-Windows-PnpCustomizationsNonWinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DriverPaths>
                <PathAndCredentials wcm:keyValue="1" wcm:action="add">
                    <Path>\Drivers</Path>
                </PathAndCredentials>
            </DriverPaths>
        </component>
        <component name = "Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DesktopOptimization>
                <GoToDesktopOnSignIn>true</GoToDesktopOnSignIn>
                <ShowWindowsStoreAppsOnTaskbar>false</ShowWindowsStoreAppsOnTaskbar>
            </DesktopOptimization>
            <OfflineUserAccounts>
                <OfflineAdministratorPassword>
                    <Value>hashed password</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </OfflineAdministratorPassword>
                <OfflineLocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action= "add" >
                        < Password >
                            < Value > hashed password</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Description>User</Description>
                        <DisplayName>User</DisplayName>
                        <Group>Users</Group>
                        <Name>User</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action= "add" >
                        < Password >
                            < Value > hashed password</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Description>Support user</Description>
                        <DisplayName>Support</DisplayName>
                        <Name>Support</Name>
                        <Group>Users</Group>
                    </LocalAccount>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action= "add" >
                        < Password >
                            < Value > hashed password</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Description>Admin user</Description>
                        <DisplayName>Admin user</DisplayName>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <Name>AdminUser</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </OfflineLocalAccounts>
            </OfflineUserAccounts>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, but first you can try to validate the answer file in *Windows System Image Manager*. Another way to get it done you can also use a second tool called *Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer*, it works fine there.

Comment: It comes trough the validation. Let me look in to the other program.

Comment: The Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer work with network shares. This is something i don't want in my configuration set. But thanks for the idea mate.

Comment: I used it to overpass the OOBE configuration process together with setting up all users and groups. The last thing that comes to my mind, maybe you meant the group of Authenticated Users instead of Users?

Comment: No it basicly adds the users but they don't got any group so they aren't able to login.

Comment: Hey, should not it be the *localgroup* instead of the *group*?